# When writing a file do we create a new file?

Tags: python, json, csv, file

Let's say I'm using these codes to write something to a file.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('Hello\n')
```

In this case, must 'somefile.txt' be an existing file or a file that we just created by writing a 'hello' message?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) :

> To create a new file in Python, use the open() method, with one of the
> following parameters:
>
> "x" - Create - will create a file, returns an error if the file exist
>
> "a" - Append - will create a file if the specified file does not exist
>
> "w" - Write - will create a file if the specified file does not exist

So in your case, using `open('somefile.txt', 'a')` with **a** as a second parameter, you are creating a file if not exists.

Comment: So if I were to create a file I could use 'w' as the second parameter right?

Comment: using `x`, `a` or `w`, in all these cases, you'll create a file ** if the specified file does not exist**

Comment: 'w' will over-write if the `somefile.txt` already exists

Answer (score 0):

When you are using "with open", it will open the file if it is already present in the folder and if is not present in the folder it will create a new file in that folder where you are running this file.